# Performance impact of storing user images as binary data vs. static files in a multi-platform project?

Tags: android, ios, django, performance

I have a project that has a web implementation developed in Django and mobile implementations in Android and iOS. One of the features is to allow users to upload images. There are various posts about storing them as binary arrays as well as storing them as static files served by a file-server. Is there any viable solution that is efficient enough for all three platforms?

Comment: Definitely as static files! :)   Static files can be cached, served via a CDN etc, even without that they are much more efficient for the web server to serve rather than loading them from the db

Comment: Thanks. Would you happen to have any idea if the same holds true for mobile platforms as well?

Comment: The performance implications of your two choices are all on the server side, so yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely as static files!

Static files can be cached by the web server, served via a CDN etc. Even without that they are more efficient for the web server to serve directly from disk, rather than have the database load them from a table.

User-uploaded files are known as 'media files' in Django, to distinguish them from 'static files' which are the parts of your website which don't change (i.e. the core design).  However when it comes to serving them the method is the same.

There are some details in the docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development
You'll see the note there that you shouldn't have Django itself serving the static or media files, except during development.  This means you need to set up the web server to serve the files.

Some details in the docs here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/deployment/

An alternative that is performant and easier to set up (and would seem to contradict the advice above) is to use:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-rednoise/

...RedNose is designed to be used in conjunction with a CDN (such as [Amazon Cloudfront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) if you're hosting on AWS) - in this case it's ok for Django to handle the static+media files because they will be ultimately be served by the CDN.

As far as issues specific to mobile performance, you should look into:
https://www.ampproject.org/

Answer (score 1):

Django provides logic for handling image uploads, see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#imagefield).
From my own experience I can tell that within a django environment it is much more convenient to let django do the work through its image fields.
Simply create a Model:

```
class UserImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='test')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

This handles all the logic for you and saves new image files to a specified directory on your server. The Advantage is that you can access the files pretty straight-forward through `http://yourdomain.com/media/test/image.png`.

Comment: Maybe my question was unclear. The way you've described essentially stores the image as a static file at the given path's referenced location. I'm trying to assess if it makes more sense to store images as static files or to save them as binary fields in a database.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that you would point your web server to serve files directly from that directory so that there is no need for them to be served through Django.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to store the data in the database for your use case. There are some use-cases when it makes sense (e.g. if you want to backup or mirror your database somewhere else, create dumps, etc.). Storing them as files on your server is the more straight-forward approach, and I'm not aware that storing them in the database would increase your performance... Put aside that you have more hassle writing and reading the data from the database directly...